# Show that a bounded sequence in $L^2$ converges in $L^2$ if it is weakly convergent

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $ \{u^{k}\}_{k\geq 1} $ be a bounded sequence in $L^2([0,T];l^2)$, where $L^2([0,T];l^2)$ is the set of functions valued in $l^2$ with norm defined by $$\lVert u\rVert_{L^2([0,T];l^2)}=\left(\int_0^T\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_n^2(s)ds\right)^{\frac{1}{2}},$$Where $u_n$ are components of u, i.e. $u:=(u_1,u_2,u_3\dots).$

Assume that the sequence $ \{u^{k}\}_{k\geq 1} $ converges weakly to $u\in L^2([0,T];l^2)$ in the following sense:
$$ \lim_{k\to\infty}\sup_{s\in[0,T]}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{(n^2)}}\frac{|u^{k}_n(s)-u_n(s)|}{1+|u^{k}_n(s)-u_n(s)|}=0. $$I want to show that the bounded sequence $ \{u^{k}\}_{k\geq 1} $ also converges to $u$ in $L^2([0,T];l^2)$. Can anyone please help me?

PS: If needed, $u^k(s)=(u^k_1(s),u^k_2(s),u^k_3(s),\dots)$ can have the property that $u^k_n$ is bounded for any $k,n,s$. Also, $u^k_n=0$ for all $n\geq k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim is false.

Let $$u^k(t)_n=\delta_{n,k}$$ where $\delta$ is Kronecker's delta.  Then $$\|u^k\|_{L^2([0,T]\to\ell^2)}=\sqrt{\int_0^T{1\,dt}}=\sqrt{T}$$ is bounded; likewise each $u^k(t)_n$ is bounded.  And yet: \begin{align*}
\lim_{k\to\infty}{\sup_{s\in[0,T]}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2^{(n^2)}}\frac{|u^{k}_n(s)|}{1+|u^{k}_n(s)|}}}}&=\lim_{k\to\infty}{\sup_{s\in[0,T]}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2^{(n^2)}}\cdot\frac{\delta_{k,n}}{2}}}} \\
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}{\sup_{s\in[0,T]}{\frac{1}{2\cdot2^{k^2}}}} \\
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}{\frac{1}{2\cdot2^{k^2}}} \\
&=0
\end{align*}  Thus $\{u^k\}_k$ converges weakly (in your sense) to $0$, but $$\limsup_{k\to\infty}{\|u^k-0\|_{L^2([0,T]\to\ell^2)}}=\sqrt{T}\neq0 $$